# How can I copy a JavaFX code that perfectly builds and runs to a remote ssh server in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, maven-compiler-plugin

I tried to copy the java project folder in remote ssh server. Then I opened Visual Studio Code and used SSH FS extension by Kelvin Schoofs to open the remote folder. Then I opened the main .java App file, and then I pressed "Play" button to compile and run java, but it does not work, it says:

```
$  cd /run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp:host=mynamesite.duckdns.org,port=9022/path/to/project ; /usr/bin/env /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk/bin/java @/tmp/cp_5b2xgbx2rjiw3h09vd2sbor51.argfile -m com.example/com.example.App 
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module com.example not found
```

But even if I just do ctrl+shift+p and do a brand new JAVAFX project, the interactive project creation fails and says:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:generate (default-cli) on project vipagepharma: Unable to add module to the current project as it is not of packaging type 'pom' -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
The terminal process "/usr/bin/bash '-c', 'mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId="javafx-archetype-fxml" -DarchetypeGroupId="org.openjfx" -DarchetypeVersion="RELEASE" -DgroupId="com.example" -DartifactId="demo"'" terminated with exit code: 1.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some of my suggestions:

First, please confirm whether the jdk you installed has JavaFX.
Then you can try to import all dependencies using `npm` and run the project.

Or You can simplify this whole process by switching to Maven based projects. A maven project has all build and dependency information in a file called pom.xml and will simplify all other dependency issues.
The steps are detailed on [Getting started with JavaFX 11 with maven](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven).

Finally, there is a VSCode extension called [Ant Target Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nickheap.vscode-ant) that might help you.

Hope this helps you.